# JS - Change the color of the result

Tags: javascript, css

I want to implement an availability status on the site based on a given hour.  I have prepared the code, but I do not know how to include the color specification.

I want to display "Online" in green, while "Offline" in red? How to do it?

```js
var today = new Date();
var time = today.getHours();
var greet;


if (time > 0 && time <= 12) {
  greet = 'Online';
} else if (time > 12 && time <= 23) {
  greet = 'Offline';
}



var show = document.getElementById('message');
show.textContent = greet;
```

```html
<p id="message"></p>
```

Comment: You must use show.style.color = "red";   you can add a var color = "red" and change it when u need to "green"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest - add greet as a class too

```js
const show = document.getElementById('message');

var today = new Date();
var time = today.getHours();
var greet;

if (time > 0 && time <= 12) {
  greet = 'Online';
} else if (time > 12 && time <= 23) {
  greet = 'Offline';
}
show.classList.add(greet)

show.textContent = greet;
```

```css
.Offline { color: red; }
.Online { color: green; }
```

```html
<p id="message"></p>
```

You can even add the text in the class

```js
const show = document.getElementById('message');
const time = new Date().getHours();
var greet;

if (time > 0 && time <= 12) {
  greet = 'Online';
} else if (time > 12 && time <= 23) {
  greet = 'Offline';
}
show.classList.add(greet)
```

```css
.Offline {
  color: red;
}

.Offline::after {
  content: "Offline"
}

.Online {
  color: green;
}

.Online::after {
  content: "Online"
}
```

```html
<p id="message"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const show = document.getElementById('message');

var today = new Date();
var time = today.getHours();
var greet;

if (time > 0 && time <= 12) {
  greet = 'Online';
} else if (time > 12 && time <= 23) {
  greet = 'Offline';
}
show.classList.add(greet)

show.textContent = greet;
```

```css
.Offline { color: red; }
.Online { color: green; }
```

```html
<p id="message"></p>
```

so if there is any help needed. Reach out. I will be online everyday

Answer (score 0):

You can select the `<p>` tag on the first line of script

```js
var today = new Date();
var time = today.getHours();
var greet;
var show = document.getElementById('message');


if (time > 0 && time <= 12) {
  greet = 'Online';
  show.style.color = "green"
} else if (time > 12 && time <= 23) {
  greet = 'Offline';
  show.style.color = "red";
}

show.textContent = greet;
```

```html
<p id="message"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var today = new Date();
var time = today.getHours();
var greet;


if (time > 0 && time <= 12) {
    greet = 'Online';
    greetColor = "green";  
} else if (time > 12 && time <= 23) {
    greet = 'Offline';
    greetColor = "red";
} 



var show = document.getElementById('message');
show.textContent = greet;
show.style.color = greetColor;
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the first example here :)
[JavaScript HTML DOM - Changing CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: noted! thanks. I thought that for simple questions a simple reference is enough as it will help the programmer to learn about the docs, in addition to getting the answer

Comment: Then please post an example and a link to a [better website than w3schools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Using_dynamic_styling_information)